# Com+ Object change Memory limit with powershell

Tags: powershell, com+

How would you change the memory limit on a com+ object with powershell?

Here I've increased the Memory Limit to 1GB using the gui.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a document on how to do this with visual basic

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684192(v=vs.85).aspx

The following powershell will increase the memory limit. You will need to change $AppID and $CLSID to the appropriate Identifiers

```
$AppID = "{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}"
$CLSID = "{22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222}"
$comAdmin = New-Object -comobject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog


function ConfigurePoolLimits ( $comAdmin , $MemoryLimit) {
    Write-Host "Configuring Pool Limits"

    $apps = $comAdmin.GetCollection("Applications")
    $apps.Populate();
    $changesMade = $false
    foreach ($app in $apps ) {
        if ($app.Name -eq $AppName ) {
            Write-Host "Found Application $($app.Name)"
            Write-Host "RecycleMemoryLimit is $($app.Value("RecycleMemoryLimit"))"
            if ($app.Value("RecycleMemoryLimit") -ne $MemoryLimit) {
                $changesMade = $true
                Write-Host "Changing RecycleMemoryLimit to $($MemoryLimit)"
                $app.Value("RecycleMemoryLimit") = $MemoryLimit
            }
        }
    }
    if ($changesMade) {
        $apps.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Then call the function with 2 parameters

```
ConfigurePoolLimits $comAdmin 1000000
```